# How to know whether someone is resizing to make it smaller or bigger in case of shapes in Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, fabricjs

I am working on Fabricjs Library and want to validate when the user is re-sizing to make the rectangle(any shape) smaller or bigger.

Means when user resizes to make it smaller then call some function and when user resizes to increase the size then call another function.

Is it possible in Fabricjs?

Comment: do you want it for window or canvas ? I think on window resize you need to calculate width of element and compare it with previous width. You will come to know whether you are increasing or decreasing width.

Comment: Its about canvas in fabric js where you can easily move/resize your objects(shapes)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use fabric's `canvas.on()` method to append [event listeners](http://fabricjs.com/events/).

The one you are looking for is `'object:scaling'` or `'object:resizing'`.
Then you just have to look to object's `scaleX` and `scaleY` or `width` and `height` properties to know if it's increasing or decreasing.

```js
var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('c');

// create a rectangle object
var rect = new fabric.Rect({
  left: 100,
  top: 100,
  fill: 'red',
  width: 20,
  height: 20
});
// one listener for the scale event (could be resize)
function scaleListener(e) {
  // get the object being rescaled
  var targ = e.target;
  // check if we the scale was bigger than the new one
  if (targ.scaleX > (targ.lastScaleX || 1) || targ.scaleY > (targ.lastScaleY || 1)) {
    // it was
    bigger();
  } else {
    // it wasn't
    smaller();
  }
  // save the current scale as the last one in the object itself
  targ.lastScaleX = targ.scaleX;
  targ.lastScaleY = targ.scaleY;
};

function bigger() {
  rect.fill = 'blue';
}

function smaller() {
    rect.fill = 'green';
  }
  // "add" rectangle onto canvas
canvas.add(rect);
canvas.on({
  'object:scaling': scaleListener,
});
```

```html
<!-- Provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/1.5.0/fabric.js"></script>
<canvas id="c"><</canvas>
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. But I want to know whether the object size is increased or decreased. I know `object:scaling` will suffice but how to know whether size is increased or reduced as event is same.

Comment: just look at object's scaleX and scaleY properties ? these are passed as parameters of the event callback. Just the same as window's resize event

Comment: I think you misunderstood the question. I need 2 functions one to detect object scaling when we increase by resizing and other for decrease while resizing. Is it clear now?

Comment: Yes that's clear, I hope the edit will also clarify what I told you about using this event

Comment: perfect , thats what I was looking for